# Given rectangle $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ st. $v(L) = r$, can we cover $L$ by countably many rectangles $Q_i$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v(Q_i) < r$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Consider a rectangle $L  = [a_1, b_1 ] \times \dots \times [a_n, b_n]\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v(L) = r$, can we cover $L$ by countably many rectangles $Q_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v(Q_i) < r$?

Note that $v(L) = (b_1 - a_1)\dots (b_n-a_n)$. Now intuitively I think the answer to this is no, however I'm not really sure how I could prove this, in the sense that if I suppose that I can find such a covering I don't see any way to reach a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by _covering_?

Comment: @BigbearZzz I mean that $L \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} Q_i$

Comment: I presume that by $v(A)$ you mean the Lebesgue measure of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course this follows from the theory of Lebesgue measure.

If you don't want to appeal to that, then consider this. One can expand
the $Q_i$ slightly so they become open but still the sum of their measures
is less than $v(L)$. As $L$ is compact, Heine-Borel shows that a finite
number of the $Q_i$ cover $L$. Now it is quite elementary that
$\sum_{i=1}^n v(Q_i)\ge v(L)$ for a finite covering of rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose that $v(A)$ coincides with the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $A$. Assuming we can find such a cover, then
$$
v(L) \le v\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i\right) 
$$
since $v$ is monotonic and $L\subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i$. However, $v$ is also subadditive, i.e. $v\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty v(A_i)$ (and equality holds when $A_i$ are disjoint), hence 
$$
r=v(L) \le v\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i\right) \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty v(Q_i) <r.
$$
This is a contradiction.

**Edit**: If your definition of the function $v$ only involves rectangular set, then it is possible to extend $v$ so that its domain is a pretty large class of subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ called the *measurable sets*. You can look up Caratheodory extension theorem if you want to know precisely what I meant.